# Odd number of elements in Perl hash

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash

I'm having some trouble with hashes. I need to get a list of version with key => value pairs into a hash but kept getting an error. The code just below is my recent attempt. Some of the strings have been changed and unneeded code isn't included.

I've looked all over the net but haven't been able to find anything that can help me. I've used Perl for a long time but haven't used hashes and arrays much. Most of my Perl experience has had to do with regex and shell execution. If I was using PHP, I would just use a multidimensional array but this is Perl and there's a lot more to the script I'm writing than what is shown or I'd switch to PHP.

I appreciate whoever takes the time to help. Thanks!

```
sub sub1 {

    # Read file which populates @rows with each line. 

    my %data;
    for (my $i=2; $i <= scalar @rows - 1; $i++) {
        $ver =~ s/\s//m;
        $data{ $ver } = [ 
            'version',  $ver,
            'available',  $table_tree->cell($jt,1)->as_text,
            'bsupport',  $table_tree->cell($jt,2)->as_text,
            'ssupport',  $table_tree->cell($jt,3)->as_text,
            'eol',  $table_tree->cell($jt,3)->as_text,
            'utype',  $table_tree->cell($jt,5)->as_text,
            'lreleases',  $table_tree->cell($jt,7)->as_text
        ];
    };
    return %data;
}

sub check_ {

    # line 199 follows

    my (%hash) = @_; 
    print Dumper (\%hash)."\n";
}

my %data = sub1($file);
check_(%data);
```

Warning:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ./file.pl line 199 (#1)
(W misc) You specified an odd number of elements to initialize a hash,
which is odd, because hashes come in key/value pairs.
```

The %hash when dumped is:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'string1' => [
               'version',
               'string1',
               'available',
               'stringa',
               'bsupport',
               'stringb',
               'ssupport',
               'stringc',
               'eol',
               'stringd',
               'utype',
               'stringe',
               'lreleases',
               'stringf'
             ],
    'string2' => [
               'version',
               'string2',
               'available',
               'stringa',
               'bsupport',
               'stringb',
               'ssupport',
               'stringc',
               'eol',
               'stringd',
               'utype',
               'stringe',
               'lreleases',
               'stringf'
             ],
    'string3' => [
               'version',
               'string3',
               'available',
               'stringa',
               'bsupport',
               'stringb',
               'ssupport',
               'stringc',
               'eol',
               'stringd',
               'utype',
               'stringe',
               'lreleases',
               'stringf'
             ],
    # ...
}
```

I was originally trying to have my has be as follows. Where $VAR1 = { 'stringN' => { ... } would be any number with any number of key => value pairs but would also get the same error. I had it working but it would always generate the error.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'string1' => {
               'version' => 'string1',
               'available' => 'stringa',
               'bsupport' => 'stringb',
               'ssupport' => 'stringc',
               'eol' => 'stringd',
               'utype' => 'stringe',
               'lreleases' => 'stringf'
             },
    'string2' => {
               'version' => 'string2',
               'available' => 'stringa',
               'bsupport' => 'stringb',
               'ssupport' => 'stringc',
               'eol' => 'stringd',
               'utype' => 'stringe',
               'lreleases' => 'stringf'
             },
    'string3' => {
               'version' => 'string3',
               'available' => 'stringa',
               'bsupport' => 'stringb',
               'ssupport' => 'stringc',
               'eol' => 'stringd',
               'utype' => 'stringe',
               'lreleases' => 'stringf'
             }
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using `[` which is the anonymous array constructor. Try using `{` instead.

And it might be a bit more idiomatic if you did:

```
 $data{ $ver } = { 
    version =>   $jver,
    available =>   $table_tree->cell($jt,1)->as_text,
 };
```

Oh, and indent your code. That `for` loop doesn't finish where you (might!) think it does. Especially - check where the `return` happens. (And what `$jt` is set to - it appears unrelated to `$i`)

Comment: Unrelated, but under the 'bit more idiomatic' heading:  `for my $i (2 .. $#rows) {`

Comment: I selected this answer because it was the right way to create the hash. My warning message actually came from an empty array that was found by adding a break point and using perl -d script.pl.